# How to distinguish a string consisting entirely of numbers from a string containing only some numbers?

Tags: python

I am in a situation where I have two .csv files, file1 and file2. file1 is consists of users list, which contains names, e-mail addresses, etc. And file2 contains user's name and empty mail address.
Below is the example.

fil1.csv

```
Name, Mail
John Doe, 123@sample.com
John Doe, john_doe2@sample.com
Anna Davis, 456@sample.com
Heather Rockwell, heather_rockwell@sample.com
sample man, man_sample@sample.com
sample woman, 999@sample.com
```

file2.csv

```
Name, Mail
Anna Davis,
Heather Rockwell,
John Doe,
sample man,
sample woman,
```

And here I want to add e-mail addresses to file2.csv.
Below is the expected output .csv file.

```
Name, Mail
Anna Davis, 456@sample.com
Heather Rockwell, heather_rockwell@sample.com
John Doe, john_doe2@sample.com
sample man, man_sample@sample.com
sample woman, 999@sample.com
```

If there are multiple Users with different email addresses, how should I write a logic that ignores emails which prefix is consists of numbers only?

I tried it but have no clue how to implement it.

```
import pandas as pd


data1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
data2 = pd.read_csv(file2)

for index, user in enumerate(data1.Name):
    if user in data2.Name.values:
        if (user.Mail[index] is not consist from numbers only):
            (add mail)
```

Could someone help me to implement this?

Comment: `email_str = '456@sample.com'`
`print(email_str.split('@')[0].isdigit())`
This should help check if initial part of email is just numbers. The rest of the code needs pandas operations which you can check elsewhere.

Comment: @shivarama23 thank you for the advise. There are some users who has e-mails that start with numbers and its the only e-mail address they have. I should have added to example, sorry.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would make one dictionary with non-digit email address and an other one with digit email address. Then, to access one user email, I'd get the value from the non-digit dict and default to the digit dict.

```
dict_non_digit = dict()
dict_digit = dict()

for index, user in enumerate(data1.Name):
    if user in data2.Name.values:
        if (user.Mail[index].split('@')[0].isdigit()):
            dict_digit[user] = user.Mail[index]
        else:
            dict_non_digit[user] = user.Mail[index]

print(dict_non_digit.get("Anna Davis", value=dict_digit["Anna Davis"]))
```

If you only want one dictionnary, you can browse `dict_digit` and add element from `dict_digit` to `dict_non_digit` if it is not already in it.